Performing a Kruskal-Wallis test and adding a compact letter display to a data frame
I would like to replicate the answer to this question, but instead of an ANOVA, I would like to perform a Kruskal-Wallis test with a post-hoc dunns test.
Here's some sample code for the ANOVA. This works and will produce the desired plot result
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)
library(tidyr)
library(FSA)

# Generate species 
species <- as.factor(rep (c("Oak", "Elm", "Ash"), each = 10))

# Generate treatments
dose_1 <- rep (c("A"), 30)
dose_2 <- rep (c ("B"), 30)
dose_3 <- rep (c("C"), 30)
dose_4 <- rep (c ("D"), 30)

# Generate results
result_1 <- c((runif(10, 9, 12)), runif(10, 14, 16), runif(10, 6, 8), (runif(10, 2, 5)), runif(10, 1, 4), runif(10, 2, 4),
              runif(10, 3, 8), runif(10, 13, 18), runif(10, 6, 9), (runif(10, 4, 7)), runif(10, 7, 11), runif(10, 3, 8))


# Combine into a sinlge dataframe
data <- data.frame (species = rep(species, 4), treatment = as.factor(c(dose_1, dose_2, dose_3, dose_4)), result = result_1)

df_aov <- data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(species) %>%
  tidyr::nest() %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(aov_results = list(aov(result ~ treatment, data = data)), 
                emm = list(emmeans::emmeans(aov_results, "treatment", type= "response")), 
                cld = list(multcomp::cld(emm, Letters = LETTERS, reverse = TRUE))) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-data, -aov_results, -emm) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(cld)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(cld = trimws(.group)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-.group)

ggplot(df_aov, aes(x= reorder(species, -emmean), y = emmean, fill = treatment))+
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity')+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower.CL, ymax = upper.CL), position = position_dodge(.9), width = 0.2) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = cld, y = upper.CL), vjust = -0.5, position = position_dodge(0.9),size = 3)

This will perform the KW test and add p values, but not the means and compact letter display.
Any suggestions please?
    df_kruskal <- data %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  tidyr::nest() %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(dunn_results = list(dunnTest(result ~ treatment , data = data, method="bonferroni",kw=TRUE)$res) ) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(dunn_results))

In response to the question from Kat, here's some edited code that first subsets each species, runs then KW test, and the recombines the results into a single data frame for a plot.
## subset for elm
elm <- subset(data, species == "Elm")
elm_test <-dunnTest(result ~ treatment , data = elm, method="bonferroni",kw=TRUE)$res

# assign letters
elm_let <- cldList(P.adj ~ Comparison, data = elm_test,threshold  = 0.05)

# compute standard error
elm_er<-tapply(elm$result,list(elm$treatment),sd,na.rm=T)/
  sqrt(tapply(elm$result,list(elm$treatment),length))

# compute means
elm_means<-tapply(elm$result,list(elm$treatment),mean,na.rm=T)

# combine results
elm <- data.frame(Species = 'Elm', treatment = unique(elm$treatment), mean = elm_means, er = elm_er, elm_let[2])

## subset for oak
oak <- subset(data, species == "Oak")
oak_test <-dunnTest(result ~ treatment , data = oak, method="bonferroni",kw=TRUE)$res

# assign letters
oak_let <- cldList(P.adj ~ Comparison, data = oak_test,threshold  = 0.05)

# compute standard error
oak_er<-tapply(oak$result,list(oak$treatment),sd,na.rm=T)/
  sqrt(tapply(oak$result,list(oak$treatment),length))

# compute means
oak_means<-tapply(oak$result,list(oak$treatment),mean,na.rm=T)

# combine results

oak <- data.frame(Species = 'Oak', treatment = unique(oak$treatment), mean = oak_means, er = oak_er, oak_let[2])

## subset for ash
ash <- subset(data, species == "Ash")
ash_test <-dunnTest(result ~ treatment , data = ash, method="bonferroni",kw=TRUE)$res

# assign letters
ash_let <- cldList(P.adj ~ Comparison, data = ash_test,threshold  = 0.05)

# compute standard error
ash_er<-tapply(ash$result,list(ash$treatment),sd,na.rm=T)/
  sqrt(tapply(ash$result,list(ash$treatment),length))

# compute means
ash_means<-tapply(ash$result,list(ash$treatment),mean,na.rm=T)

# combine results

ash <- data.frame(Species = 'Ash', treatment = unique(ash$treatment) , mean = ash_means, er = ash_er, ash_let[2])


plot_data <- rbind(ash, oak, elm)



ggplot(plot_data, aes( x = treatment, y = mean))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = 'grey70')+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - er, ymax = mean + er), position = position_dodge(.9), width=.1, linewidth = .7, col = 'black')+
  facet_wrap(~ Species)+
  theme_bw()+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,20))+
  geom_text(aes(label = Letter, y = (mean + er)), vjust = -1, position = position_dodge(0.9),size = 5, col = 'black')



The Dunn Test is a post hoc, usually done with Kruskal Wallis...it isn't Kruskal Wallis - per se. However, the bigger issue is that for tests like ANOVA and estimated means - there's a value for each side of the formula (x and y, for example). For Kruskal Wallis and the Dunn Test, there is one value that represents the comparison between groups, not two. So instead of an A & a B from ANOVA, there's an A-B from Kruskal-Wallis. That being said, now how do you envision your plot so that I can still help?

@Kat - I've added some additional code to the original code so you can see the mechanics of what I'm trying to achieve and what the desired plot would look like

I've been going through this code, but I can't figure out what the letters represent in order to reproduce the code. Anything that's not significant is excluded, (not a great idea...) and of that which is significant, using Ash for example: A-B, B-C, and B-D ... are somehow 4 groups with 4 letters: a, b, a, a? Then the average standard deviation by group (A-D) is applied to each of these 4 groups? I think I'm missing the bigger picture of you're visualizing. Can you explain what these characters represent and how that relates to the Kruskal-Wallis test or the post hoc Dunn Test?
